# How to pick a highest value from text inputs names and add another field with higher value?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a function, which createssets of text inputs:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var scntDiv = $('#textfields');
    var i = $('#textfields p').size() + 2;
    var a = 0;
    $('#addbutton').click (function() {
        $('<p><input type="text" id="test_testbutton" name="test_testbutton['+a+'][0]" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /><input type="text" id="test_testbutton" name="test_testbutton['+a+'][1]" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /><a href="#" id="removebutton">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
        i++;
        a++;
        return false;
    });
    $('#removebutton').live('click',function() { 
        if( i > 2 ) {
        $(this).parents('p').remove();
        i--;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

as you can see it puts in every input's 'name' field a incremented value. It looks like:

```
name="test_testbutton[0][0]",  name="test_testbutton[1][0]", name="test_testbutton[2][0]", etc.
```

The function can remove selected input on demand. It is connected with some PHP code (doesn't matter what the code look like), which saves everything and stores as an array. When Array is created the saved inputs are displayed. They have the same numbers in 'name' field as previously cerated field by above function. so it looks like:

```
<p><input type="text" id="" name="test_testbutton[0][0]" value="" placeholder="" />
<input type="text" id="" name="test_testbutton[0][1]" value="" placeholder="" /></p>

<p><input type="text" id="" name="test_testbutton[1][0]" value="" placeholder="" />
<input type="text" id="" name="test_testbutton[1][1]" value="" placeholder="" /></>
```

and so on......

But the problem appears when, after saving, I want to add another text inputs. My jQuery function starts counting from 0. I'd like it to find a highest value of every 'name' fields and create another inputs with higher value, for example:

if the 'name' of input with highest value is 'name="test_testbutton[25][0]' after clcking 'Add' it creates 'name="test_testbutton[26][0]', and so on...

And now!.. my question, badam tsss!!: how to achieve it?

---

**EDIT!**

The whole PHP code is based on form submitting. I think I didn't give enough details about PHP code relative to my jQuery function, so there it is:

Function directly relative to jQuery I provided above, it stores inputs texts as an array 'test_testbutton', thanks to code presented below everything is displayed back as a inputs sets:

```
<a href="#" id="addbutton">Add</a>
<div id="textfields">
    <?php
if (isset($_POST['test_testbutton']) && is_array($_POST['test_testbutton'])) {
    $_POST['test_testbutton'];}

$textfields = get_option('test_testbutton');
    if (!empty($textfields)) {
        foreach ($textfields as $key => $textfield):?>
<p><input type="text" id="test_testbutton" name="test_testbutton[<?php echo $key;?>][0]" value="<?php echo $textfield[0];?>" placeholder="Input Value" /><input type="text" id="test_testbutton" name="test_testbutton[<?php echo $key;?>][1]" value="<?php echo $textfield[1];?>" placeholder="Input Value" /><a href="#" id="removebutton">Remove</a></p><?php
    endforeach;}
?>
</div>
```

And a function which saves everything in database on submit:

```
function theme_settings_page() {
    global $themename,$theme_options;
    $i=0;
    $message='';
        if ( 'save' == $_REQUEST['action'] ) {

            foreach ($theme_options as $value) {
        update_option( $value['id'], $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ] ); }

            foreach ($theme_options as $value) {
        if( isset( $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ] ) ) { update_option( $value['id'], $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ]  ); } else { delete_option( $value['id'] ); } }
$message='saved';
}

else if( 'reset' == $_REQUEST['action'] ) {

            foreach ($theme_options as $value) {
        delete_option( $value['id'] ); }
$message='reset';
}
        if ( $message=='saved' && $i==0 )  echo '<div id="message" class="apply"><strong>Saved.</strong></div>' ;
        if ( $message=='reset' ) echo '<div id="message" class="reset"><strong>Reset.</strong></div>';

?>
```

So again, I need a function which searches through all 'test_testbutton['+a+'][0]' values on website after they being saved on submit, and when I click Add button it puts in place of ['+a+'] 'highest value +1'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for bothering you guys, I really am (I didn't give you enough details to answer my question properly:()! I found a seamless solution by myself. What i did is to move the whole jQuery code into a PHP file, then I found a highest array's key value and usedin a jQuery loop, here it is:

```
<input name="save" class="addbutton button" type="submit" value="+" />
<div id="textfields">
    <?php
if (isset($_POST[$value['id']]) && is_array($_POST[$value['id']])) {
    $_POST[$value['id']];}

$textfields = get_option($value['id']);
    if (!empty($textfields)) {
        foreach ($textfields as $key => $textfield):
            ?><p><input type="text" id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" name="<?php echo $value['id'];?>[<?php echo $key;?>][0]" value="<?php echo $textfield[0];?>" placeholder="Input Value" /><input type="text" id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" name="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>[<?php echo $key;?>][1]" value="<?php echo $textfield[1];?>" placeholder="Input Value" /><a href="#" id="removebutton">Remove</a></p>
<?php endforeach;
     $max = max(array_keys($textfields))+1;}
     else {
    $max = 0;}
?>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    var scntDiv = $('#textfields');
    var i = $('#textfields p').size() + 2;
    var x = <?php echo $max;?>;
    var a = x;
    $('.addbutton').click (function() {
        $('<p><input type="text" id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" name="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>['+a+'][0]" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /><input type="text" id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" name="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>['+a+'][1]" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /><a href="#" id="removebutton">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
        i++;
        a++;
        return false;
    });
    $('#removebutton').live('click',function() {
        if( i > 2 ) {
        $(this).parents('p').remove();
        i--;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

now, everytime I click 'Add' It looks for higest key value and add an input filed with Key + 1 value :)

Answer (score 0):

Use cookies to hold value of `a` among reloads:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var scntDiv = $('#textfields');
    var i = $('#textfields p').size() + 2;
    var a = $.cookie("testButtonCount");;
    $('#addbutton').click (function() {
        $('<p><input type="text" id="test_testbutton" name="test_testbutton['+a+'][0]" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /><input type="text" id="test_testbutton" name="test_testbutton['+a+'][1]" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /><a href="#" id="removebutton">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
        i++;
        a++;
        $.cookie("testButtonCount", a);
        return false;
    });
    $('#removebutton').live('click',function() { 
        if( i > 2 ) {
        $(this).parents('p').remove();
        i--;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

This solution requires [this plug-in](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

Comment: I downloaded the plug-in and installed it. i used your function, but it doesn't work. Instead of succeeding numbers as I add next inputs row I receive NaN. Or maybe I don't know how to use it properly...

Comment: Forgot to mention. In your PHP code you need to add conditional loop generating `<input>` (by iteration to `testButtonCount` count) fields if `testButtonCount` is set. [The Doc](http://www.php.net/manual/pl/reserved.variables.cookies.php) may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the save/remove php via an ajax call, you can save the count (_a) in a DOM variable. Put IDs on your container elements and it makes it easier to remove them.

```
    var _a = 0;
        jQuery(function($) {
            var scntDiv = $('#textfields');
            $('#addbutton').click (function() {
                $('<p id="p'+_a+'"><input type="text" id="test_testbutton" name="test_testbutton['+_a+'][0]" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /><input type="text" id="test_testbutton" name="test_testbutton['+_a+'][1]" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /><a href="#" onclick="removeRow('+_a+');return false;">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
                _a++;
                $.post('save.php', {id:_a});
                return false;
            });
        });

        function removeRow(id){
            if( $('#textfields p').size() > 2 ) {
                $.post('remove.php',{id: id});
                $('#p'+id).remove();
                // don't decrease _a on the remove. Keeps your ids unique
            }
        }
```

Comment: I forgot to add 'save' function code, your example doesn't work beacuse I didn't give enough details. See EDIT in my question please.

Comment: It's not going to work unless you have a save.php and a remove.php handling your requests. I was just showing an example of how you could add/remove items from your page and where to put your server side handlers. You stated your problem was a counter being reset to zero. Using silent posts with ajax allows you to increment/decrement a server side variable and keep it in synch with what your client value is. It's going to be set to 0 if you refresh the page or do a post back. You could always do a full post once all the boxes are set. Your php page then has all the info to pull from your post.

Comment: I'm guessing you are doing something in WordPress?

Comment: Yes, it's Wordpress. Sorry to bother you but I found a worakround by myself and it reqired a bit of strenuous thinking, as I'm a newbe in PHP/jQuery stuff. I moved whole jQuery code to PHP file, I stored a highest aray's key value and ut in into above jQuery funciot. Works like a charm!!

Comment: No worries. If it works great. WP is a great platform but does have some constraints to consider when trying to step outside its native way of handling requests.